# MongoDB:Convert day month year to timestamp in $project

Tags: mongodb

Please help me!
After grouping by day , i have got this :

{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2017,
        "month" : 11,
        "day" : 8
    },
    "count" : 142.0
}

and this is what i want , 
but i need to convert this day in timestamp like 1510221787000 , 
is that possible with a simple project ? i tried this but doesn't work:

```
{
  $project:{
      "newdate": new Date("$_id.year","$_id.month","$_id.day"),
      "count":1
  }
```

}

thank you in advance.

Comment: The solution of course it "don't split up the date into "year", "month" and "day" when grouping. There are other ways you can "round" the date instead.

Comment: thank you chridam & Neil , i'll try to round the date as Neil suggestion .